# Randomly get nodes from XML using XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am making a website using a CMS, in the home page I need to get some Pictures and discriptions randomly,, I need each time i refresh the page to get new nodes.

This is how I am calling the nodes in XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select ="TSPRoot/Blocks/Block[@ID=134]/Articles/Article[position() &lt; 4]">
          <div class="layout-08">
            <a class="title" href="detailed.aspx?id={ID}">
              <xsl:choose >
                <xsl:when test ="string-length(ImageURL) > 0">
                  <img src="_handlers/resizeimage.ashx?src={ImageURL}&amp;height=149&amp;width=206" title="{Headline}"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <img src="_frontend/ux/images/en_logo.png" width="206" height="149" title="{Headline}"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </a>
            <div class="bg">
              <a href="detailed.aspx?id={ID}"><xsl:value-of select ="Headline"/></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

This gets the newest (3) nodes, I need random (3) nodes each time i refresh.

Comment: What should random mean in this context?  You can use a variable instead of the const value "4".

Comment: I mean I need random 3 nodes each time i reload the page ,,,

Comment: I need to get diffrent pics each time i reload

Answer (score 0):

I would give you only some ideas of possible solution.
Technically XSLT doesn't offer a method random numbers. However, this problem can be solved in at least three different ways:

1. Generate pseudo-random number in Java/C#/PHP code before executing XSLT template and pass the generated number as an XSLT parameter.
2. Use the extension function:  http://exslt.org/random/functions/random-sequence/index.html
3. Use `current-dateTime()` (XSLT 2.0) function as a seed for your random number procedure. With a couple of string and math operations you could convert it into desired quasi-random number. I think that for your needs this solution is enough.

**EDIT - Ad 3.**

I have made some experiments with this idea. And I have created some sample code. I know that this code generate a sequence of really **pseudo** random numbers, but for simple web page like in the question it might be enough.

The following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:rnd="http://whatever.org/random">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:function name="rnd:pseudoRandomInternal">
        <xsl:param name="numSeed" as="xs:decimal"/>
        <xsl:variable name="squareSeed" select="xs:string($numSeed*$numSeed)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="oneDivSeed" select="substring($squareSeed, 3, string-length($squareSeed) - 3)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cc" select="if (string-length($oneDivSeed) > 6) then 
            substring($oneDivSeed, string-length($oneDivSeed) - 6) else 
            $oneDivSeed"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal($cc)"/>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:function name="rnd:pseudoRandom" as="xs:decimal*">
        <xsl:param name="range" as="xs:integer"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$range = 1">
                <xsl:variable name="seed" select="substring(xs:string(current-time()), 1, 12)" as="xs:string"/>
                <xsl:variable name="numSeed" select="xs:decimal(translate($seed, ':.+-', ''))"/>
                <xsl:sequence select="(rnd:pseudoRandomInternal($numSeed))" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="subSequence" select="rnd:pseudoRandom($range - 1)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="newValue" select="rnd:pseudoRandomInternal($subSequence[1])" as="xs:decimal*"/>
                <xsl:sequence select="($newValue, $subSequence)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="rr" select="rnd:pseudoRandom(10)" as="xs:decimal*"/>

        <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="$rr">
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select=". * 3 mod 11" />
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

generated the following output:

```
<output>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>4</item>
</output>
```

Comment: Thanks alot Lukasz Baran ,, I'll study these options and I'll reply after solving the issue.

Comment: Dear Lukasz Baran, I still can't solve thw issue, actually for the first solution you suggested I ahd a peoblem with XsltSettings.EnableScript property.
And about the etention function and the current-dateTime() I need help with them, the current-dateTime() seems like a great idea but how I can make a random number out of it, and how I can use it, since the positoin and the ID are not totaly random, thier might be only 10 entires while i am using a random number of only 10 , or there might be less entires than the random number ,, Actually I don't know what to do at all :(

Comment: Ok, i'll try to help you. one question: how is your xslt invoked? is it invoked from code in another language?

Comment: OK, I am a trainee working through our company CMS (Truthsoft) -Jordan Middle East- in Visual Studio 2010 with VB and SQL server database.
The XSL is generated from VB code, and the scripts in XSL are disabled  on the system (XsltSettings.EnableScript property.)

Comment: Is this enough for you to tell how the xsl is being "invoked" ?

Comment: I mean the XML is generated from VB code, and the XSL is invoked by VB code.

Comment: @TruthSoft have you seen my edit? Unfortunately I don't know VB XSLT engine - I haven't been working with .NET for years:(

Comment: I've just seen that, I follow the post by my feedly and it don't tell about edits.
It is 7 P.M here in Jordan, I'll I am gonna try it first thing tomorrow. Thanks alot :)